# Coinbase API: Create bitcoin wallet for app registered users

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, client, coinbase.com, php

I am a PHP newbie. I want to develop a web app to store,send,retrieve bitcoins. I need to create wallet for each users. Our idea is to use any online wallet service such as blockchain.info or coinbase. In coinbase it allow us to create multiple account for existing user. Does coinbase allow for automatic creation of users and wallet(when user registers my app) through their api.

Comment: Please reconsider. Think about whether it's a good idea to make yourself responsible for the money of other people when you admit publicly that you don't possess the skills and knowledge to do so safely.